# Magento 2 remove options from item cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to remove the customs options from the item car with this code.

```
public function beforeupdateItems(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject,$data){

    foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
    $item = $subject->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
    $optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids');

                if ($optionIds) {
                    foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {

                        $item->removeOption('option_' . $optionId);
                    }
                    $item->removeOption('option_ids');
                }

                $item->save();
    }

return [$data];
}
```

I want to remove the custom options for the products that are in the cart. And add the news selected.

When I edit a product from the route `localhost/checkout/cart/` Magento go to `localhost/checkout/cart/configure/id/[number_quote]/product_id/[number_product]/` and render this:

[image]

If you pulse on **"update button"** then Magento remove all the options and add the new selected.

I want to know how Magento do this process.

I think that if in the `checkout/cart` **"Shopping Cart"** when I submit on **"updating shopping cart button"** if I created a module with one plugin. In this plugin I can to execute the code to remove the custom options and add the news selected.

[image]

Then I use **"beforeUpdateItems"** to execute the code,

But when I go back to the Shopping Cart the options continue in the products.

Thanks for your help!

**[***** SOLUTION *****]**

Hi everybody I found the solution. In the code change $item->save(); to:

> $item->saveItemOptions();

Regards!!